# Why does F# infer this type?

Tags: .net, f#, types, type-inference

This is my code:

```
type Cell<'t>(initial : 't) =
    let mutable v = initial
    let callbacks = new List<'t -> unit>()
    member x.register c = callbacks.Add(c)
    member x.get () = v
    member x.set v' = 
        if v' <> v 
        then v <- v'
             for callback in callbacks do callback v'
    member x.map f = 
        let c = new Cell<_>(f v)
        x.register(fun v' -> c.set (f v')) ; c
```

My problem is with the `map` member. F# infers the type

```
map : ('t -> 't) -> Cell<'t>
```

I think it should infer this more general type (just like Seq's map):

```
map : ('t -> 'a) -> Cell<'a>
```

And in fact if I declare the type like that, Visual Studio tells me that the type 'a has been constrained to 't because of the expression `(f v')` in `c.set (f v')`. Is the problem that the new Cell is forced to have type Cell<'t> because we're in the class definition?

I'm pretty sure that's the problem because if I define map as a separate function then F# does infer the type I want:

```
let map f (c : Cell<_>) = 
    let c' = new Cell<_>(f (c.get ()))
    c.register(fun v' -> c'.set (f v')) ; c'
```

Namely

```
map : ('a -> 'b) -> Cell<'a> -> Cell<'b>
```

I would like to use a member, but this less general type makes my Cell type useless... How do I solve this problem?

Thanks!
Jules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a box with Beta1 handy right now (in our internal bits this now seems to infer the correct type, so hopefully that means this will be fixed in Beta2).

I expect you can specify a full type signature:

```
    member x.map<'a> (f:'t -> 'a) : Cell<'a> =
```

and it will work.

**UPDATE**

I tried on Beta1, and in fact the 'fix' is

```
member x.set (v':'t) : unit =
```

I am unclear why adding this type signature helps.

Comment: Thanks! That signature is strange: if you remove `: unit` or if you remove `v' : 't` then F# infers the restricted type again! And if you don't specify the signature F# infers the same type... Thanks again!