# Unknown need for type annotation or cast

Tags: f#, type-inference

I know I must be missing something really obvious here. `B.GetInstance().Call()` generates the error: *Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.*

I'm using v1.9.9.9.

```
type A() =
    member x.Call() = B.GetInstance().Call()

and B() =
    static member GetInstance() = new B()
    member x.Call() = ()
```

I just discovered that this works: `(B.GetInstance() :> B).Call()`

Any idea why the cast is necessary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Frequently when you've got a recursive set of methods whose types to infer, F# needs help.  A more pleasant alternative would be to annotate the definition of `B.GetInstance`:

```
type A() =
  member x.Call() = B.GetInstance().Call()

and B() =
  static member GetInstance() : B = new B()
  member x.Call() = ()
```

I believe that the reason you run into this problem is that F# tries to solve all inferred types on all methods in A and B simultaneously (because they are defined as mutually recursive types), and this leads to problems, but perhaps someone from the F# team will weigh in.

Comment: That's not intuitive to understand it. Saved my day, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The quick summary is that in a recursive group (e.g. members in one type, or members of recursive types like we have here) F# reads the *declarations* in left-to-right top-to-bottom order, followed by the *definitions* in left-to-right top-to-bottom order.  So in this instance when it reaches the definition of `A.Call`, it has not yet read the *definition* of `B.GetInstance` and therefore does not (yet!) know that the return type of `GetInstance` will be `B`.

Keith's answer nails it for this situation, you can provide a type annotation to specify the return type of `GetInstance` in its declaration.

See

[Forcing F# type inference on generics and interfaces to stay loose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809405/forcing-f-type-inference-on-generics-and-interfaces-to-stay-loose/1809604#1809604)

for a deep discussion of what's going on here.

Note also that in your original attempt, you don't need to "cast" (the potentially dynamic operation, using `:>`), instead you can just "annotate" (statically declare a type, using `:`) to get it to compile.  But makes more sense to put the type annotation in the method declaration for `GetInstance` (generally, prefer addition annotations to method signatures instead of arbitrary places inside bodies).