# How to make F# infer common base type?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, inheritance, f#, type-inference

Consider this:

```
module Module1 =
    type A() = class end
    type B() = inherit A()
    type C() = inherit A()

    let f x = if x > 0 then new B() else new C()
```

The last line yields an error about type B being expected, but type C being found instead.
Ok, I can pretend to understand that: the compiler doesn't know which common base to infer in case there are many.

But guess what? Even when I specify the function type, it still doesn't work:

```
    let f x : A = if x > 0 then new B() else new C()
```

Now this gives me two errors: "*A expected, B found*" and "*A expected, C found*".
WTF? Why can't it see that both B and C are implicitly convertible to A?

Yes, I do know that I could use `upcast`, like so:

```
    let f x : A = if x > 0 then upcast new B() else upcast new C()
```

But guess what (again)? `upcast` only works in the presence of the explicit function type declaration!
In other words, this:

```
    let f x = if x > 0 then upcast new B() else upcast new C()
```

still gives an error.

WTF?! Do I really have to add 50% of noise to my program just to help the compiler out?
What's with all that hype about F# code being clean and noiseless?

Somehow it feels like this cannot be true.
So the question is: am I missing something? How do I make this both compact and working?

Comment: subtyping and type inference do not get along well.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci - I don't speak for Don or the team.  However, I'm not sure that I'd recommend emailing fsbugs when questions about design decisions come up - I think it's really meant for bug reports and feature suggestions.

Comment: F# does try to alleviate (or steer you away from) such situations by providing alternatives like [object expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233237.aspx).

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci: I didn't really mean to suggest a design change. My initial assumption was that the design does not really have this limitation, and that there is some easy way to achieve what I want. I now see from the answers, however, that this is indeed a recognized limitation and that it is backed by some more or less legitimate reasons. This is all I wanted to know.

Comment: @Daniel: Perhaps I should have been clearer on this, but I did not end up in this situation in the course of regular program design. I have encountered this while trying to interoperate with the rest of .NET, where I had to return different derived objects based on some conditions.

Comment: @kvb You're right--I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci: You shouldn't have. Now passers-by will have no idea what we're all talking about. :-)

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: You could give specific examples. Perhaps there are other ways to approach it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type inference and subtyping do not play well together, as Carsten's links discuss to some extent.  It sounds like you are unhappy with F#'s approach and would prefer it if

```
if b then 
    e1 
else 
    e2
```

were implicitly treated more like

```
if b then (e1 :> 'a) else (e2 :> 'a)
```

with the compiler additionally inferring `'a` to be the least upper bound in the type hierarchy based on the types that would otherwise be inferred for `e1` and `e2`.

It might be technically possible to do this, and I can't definitively speak to why F# doesn't work this way, but here's a guess: if `if` statements behaved this way then it would never be an error to have different types in the `if` and `else` branches, since they could always be unified by implicitly upcasting them to `obj`.  However, in practice this is almost always a programmer error - you almost always want the types to be the same (e.g. if I return a character from one branch and a string from the other, I probably meant to return strings from both, not `obj`).  By implicitly upcasting, you would merely make the presence of these errors harder to find.

Furthermore, it's relatively rare in F# to deal with complicated inheritance hierarchies, except perhaps when interoperating with other .NET code.  As a result, this is a very minor limitation in practice.  If you're looking for a syntactically shorter solution than `upcast`, you might try `:> _`, which will work as long as there is something to constrain the type (either an annotation on the overall result, or a specific cast on one of the branches).

Comment: It does not have to be "any base class". As I wrote in my question, I can pretend to understand this when the common base is ambiguous. But in my second example, where I explicitly specify the type of `f` to be `A`, it would be safe to assume that this is the type I need, wouldn't it? In other words, the compiler could treat every expression as if it had that `:> _` at the end.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: I may be wrong, but type annotations are intended only to _help_ type inference. If they worked as you stated they would change the semantics of the program, as they would serve to _constrain_ the type, not merely make it explicit. All that to say, it seems it would be a foundational change.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - perhaps.  One issue may be that similar constraints are propagated from other contexts all the time (e.g. if I do `(if true then 'c' else "string").ToString()` then does the compiler insert an implicit coercion to `obj` since that's where `ToString()` comes from, and is that treated the same way as a user-entered constraint?).  Overall, does complicating the inference mechanisms for a case which doesn't arise much in practice make sense?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - in general, compromises need to be made when trying to apply type inference to a language that supports inheritance and method overloading.  Even for C#, where non-trivial inheritance hierarchies are much more common, a similar problem arises: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087304/the-c-sharp-conditional-operator-gets-confused-but-why.

Comment: @kvb: Ok, I now see the [more or less] legitimate reasons behind this limitation. And, more importantly, I understand that this is not an oversight, but rather a conscious decision. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

there is a reason for all of this but to make it short: F# is more strong typed than C# so you have to tell where to cast to (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx)):

```
let f x = if x > 0 then (new B() :> A) else (new C() :> A)
```

Here you can find further information: [F# need for cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255602/unknown-need-for-type-annotation-or-cast)

And here is another great [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162387/why-is-fs-type-inference-so-fickle) on this.

Comment: Can you please make it long? What is the reason for all this?

Comment: Yep, I've read those. In a nutshell, they all say that this is how F# is, so deal with it. I don't see any objective reasons for this particular design decision - upcasts being not implicit.

Comment: Well this and the fact you want a good type interference - there is a paper making this much clearer but I just cannot find it right now ...