# F#: the generic member has been used at a non-uniform instantiation prior to this program point

Tags: generics, f#

I have two recursively defined classes that can be compiled in one order, but can't be compiled in another order. The simplified version of the code looks as follows:

```
type Loader() =
    member this.Load path =
        let ref = Ref()
        ref.Wait()
        ref

and Ref<'T>(data: obj) =
    member this.Foo = 1
    member this.Wait () = ()
    member this.Value = data :?> 'T
```

The error is in this.Wait() declaration; full text is as follows:

```
asset.fs(11,21): error FS1198: The generic member 'Wait' has been used at a non-uniform
instantiation prior to this program point. Consider reordering the members so this
member occurs first. Alternatively, specify the full type of the member explicitly,
including argument types, return type and any additional generic parameters
and constraints.
```

Note that in the simplified version there is really no need for recursion - however, the actual code does need the two declarations to be recursive.

I can solve this by specifying type for Wait (), as noted in error message (i.e. member `this.Wait (): unit = ()`) - however, I would like to understand why I need to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, I cite [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809405/forcing-f-type-inference-on-generics-and-interfaces-to-stay-loose) by @Brian:

> Very often the 'fix' is just to add one full type signature (including
>   return type) to some key method that is 'declared late' but 'called
>   early' (introducing a forward reference among the set of members).

In your case of mutually recursive classes, when `ref.Wait()` is invoked F# type inference looks into type declaration of `Ref` and its first member to resolve type signature of `Wait`. Since no information is available at this point, it wrongly infers signature of `Wait` as `unit -> 'a`. Looking up the first member of a class is my observation based on the following example:

```
type Loader() =    
    member this.Load path =
        let ref = Ref()
        ref.Wait()        
        ref
    member this.Load2 path =
        let ref = Ref()
        ref.Wait2()        
        ref

and Ref<'T>(data: obj) =        
    member this.Wait () = () // resolve correctly
    member this.Wait2 () = () // fail to resolve     
    member this.Foo = 1
    member this.Value = data :?> 'T
```

BTW, there are many ways to bypass this restriction:

1. Provide type annotation for *declare-late and call-early* methods.
2. Declare `Wait` as the first member in `Ref` (it is not scalable as shown in above example).
3. Declare `Ref` as the first type in the mutually recursive pair. Because `Ref` needs more information from `Loader` than the other way around, it is better to resolve `Ref` first to provide information for resolving `Loader`.

Comment: The question is, what is the Wait's type in the first inference at the place of invocation. I would expect it to be unit -> unit (see Tomas answer above), not unit -> 'a.

Comment: Just checked - changing the calling code to ref.Wait() : unit fixes the problem as well, so you must be right - the Wait type is inferred to be unit -> 'a, and later constrained to unit -> unit by declaration, which is apparently not allowed. Thanks!

Comment: @zeuxcg: it is notable that changing the line to `let () = ref.Wait2()` does not fix the error, although the constraining force of this construct should be no less than that of the explicit ` : unit`. Something fishy is going on. I think there is a subtle bug in compiler type inference.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know enough about the type checking to explain the behaviour (and I don't think the [F# specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.pdf) explains this, because it only mentions "recursive types" briefly on page 120).

Anyway, the specification says that the compiler checks recursive type definitions as a single group and so uses of a method like `Wait` are used to (partially) infer its type. When you specify the type explicitly, then the explicit definition overrides the inferred one.

In your example, the problem only appears when `Ref<'T>` is a generic type. When you call `Wait`, the compiler probably correctly infers that the method type is `unit -> unit`, but I think there is some flexibility in the `this` parameter of the method (it is `Ref<'T>` for some `'T`).

Based on the [compiler source code](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/tc.fs), the error is reported only when adding of some constraint related to the `this` variable fails (line 8914) when processing the definition of `Wait` method. So, my guess is that some constraint related to the `ref` value inside `Load` later clashes with some constraint generated from `Wait` (when the compiler gets to check the method and doesn't have full anotations to know the type for sure).

Comment: Does it look like a bug to you? Or rather a real incompleteness in the type system? But I do not see why the type could not be inferred, really.

Comment: I think the Wait() is inferred to be unit -> 'a at the call site, see accepted answer and my comment to it.

Comment: @zeuxcg I'm pretty sure it is in some way related to the `this` reference, but I don't really understand how (but that's when the error gets reported in the compiler code). F# can infer that return type is `unit` from the way computatins are sequenced - if you write `let rec foo a = bar a; 1
and bar a = a`, then `bar` is inferred to return `unit` (from the use in `foo`).

Comment: @TomasPetricek Yup, that's what I thought as well - however, then it does not make sense that explicitly specifying the type of this.Wait() expression as unit solves the issue...